# Critical error while freeing memory

Tags: c++

I have a structure "Indices" containing buffer for indices (DirectX, but I think it doesn't matter):

```
struct Indices {
    CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> buffer;
    UINT indexCount;
};
```

and a method which initializes array with objects of class Indices:

```
mIndices = new Indices*[layers];
for( int i = 0; i < layers; ++i )
    mIndices[i] = new Indices[corrections];

//... initializing buffers
```

and method which frees memory:

```
for( int i = 0; i < layers; ++i )
    delete mIndices[i];                // here I am getting critical error

delete mIndices;
```

but when I try to release the memory I am getting "Critical error detected c0000374" (pointed out in the code above).

Could you help me, please? I hope the posted code will be enough to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: You should be using `delete[]`. Not sure that is the problem though.

Comment: @Nick I'm such an idiot. This is the result of writing in java 8 hours a day. Please, write an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You should be using delete[] in two places: delete [] mIndices[i] and delete [] mIndices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are allocating arrays, you should be deallocating arrays. Use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Answer (score 5):

When you create arrays with new T[n], you also have to use delete[] to release the memory:

```
for( int i = 0; i < layers; ++i )
    delete[] mIndices[i];

delete[] mIndices;
```

Manual memory management is a hazzle, leading easily to crashes and memory leaks. Have you considered std::vector? It can be used as a drop-in replacement for dynamic arrays:

```
// create and initialize the arrays
std::vector< std::vector<Indices> > indices(layers, std::vector<Indices>(corrections));

// will be automatically freed when lifetime ends
```